# vaex groupby gives TypeError: unhashable type: 'Expression' when reading data from multiple hdf5 files

Tags: python, hdf5, vaex

In Python, I open a data frame from multiple hdf5 files with vaex (`vdf = vaex.open('test_*.hdf5')`). Everything seems to work nicely, e.g. combining two columns to make a new one (`vdf['newcol'] = vdf.x+vdf.y`).

But I cannot get vaex's groupby to work: `vdf.groupby('x', agg='count')` throws a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Expression'`.

It doesn't seem to matter if `x` is an integer column or a string column. It works nicely when I'm reading only one hdf5 file, but fails as soon as multiple files are combined into one vaex data frame. What could be the reason for this error and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Vaex are you running? If the following example works for you, that means it is fixed when installed from source:

```
import vaex
import vaex.ml

df1 = vaex.ml.datasets.load_iris()
df2 = vaex.ml.datasets.load_iris()

df = vaex.concat([df1, df2])
df.groupby('class_', agg='count')
```

If the above example works for you, you can already try the latest alpha from `pip`.